# Why is $f(x)=\langle Ax, x\rangle $ twice continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=\langle Ax, x \rangle$. Prove that $f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}^N)$.

I figured that $\nabla f(x)=(A+A^T)x$  and $H_f(x)=A+A^t$ but I don't really know what to prove in order to show $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$

Comment: If the Hessian is constant, then the second partial derivatives are continuous, right?

Comment: Well, yes that's true.

Comment: So that would be enough two show $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$?

Comment: It is a polynomial function. Sums and products of smooth functions is smooth. If $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ are the projections. Then $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\pi_i(x)\overline{\pi_j(x)}\langle Ae_i,e_j\rangle$ is a sum of products of the $\pi_i$.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to see that it is a composition of $C^{\infty}$ functions. You have $g: \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(x,y)= \langle x, y\rangle$ and $h: \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N$ such that $g(x)=(Ax,x)$. Then $f= g \circ h$.